# How can you prevent the browser from prompting you to choose the download file's location in a Frontend application?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, frontend

In my React code, I am seeking a way for users to directly download a file to their browser's designated location **without prompting them to choose a location**. I understand that adjusting this setting is possible directly within the browser, and it might not be feasible to change this behavior. Nevertheless, **I am hoping to achieve this standard setup if possible.**

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Warm regards,
Marcelo

Comment: It's not possible because this a user's decision, not yours. As it would take control away from the user, this feature doesn't exist.